Probability of points in same arc
Let $X_1,\cdots,X_4$ be iid Unif($0,2\pi$) random variables representing $4$ points on the unit circle. What is the probability that they all belong to an arc of length $\pi/2$?
I wanted to use law of total probability (on the arc they must belong to). Suppose the arc starts at point $X \sim Unif(0,2\pi)$ and has length $\pi/2$ (counter clockwise). Let $A$ be the probability we are interested in. Then
$$P(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(A | X=x)f_X(x)dx = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\big(\frac{\pi/2}{2 \pi}\big)^4\cdot \frac{1}{2 \pi}dx=\frac {1}{256}$$
Here, $P(A | X=x)$ is the probability that all points belong to the arc starting at angle $X$ and has length $\pi/2$ counter clockwise so it is equal to $\big(\frac{\pi/2}{2 \pi}\big)^4$.
I know the answer is wrong but would like to know what's wrong with it.

what's the radius?

@vallev $1$ as I meant by unit circle, sorry if it wasn't clear

Edited to distinguish between arc length and arc radian measure. Now, the discrete version of LOTP is $P(A)=P(A|B_1)P(B_1)+...+P(A|B_n)P(B_n)$. What are the events $A$ and $B_i$ being considered here?

Im using the continuous case here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Continuous_case , the event I specified the event A above and the "$B_i$" are the arc possibilities (infinitely many)

Hand wavy explanation: when you invoke law of total probability, you break them into disjoint events and then apply the law of conditional probability within each event. I don't think the events that $4$ points lie in an arc of length $\pi/2$ starting at $x$ are necessarily disjoint. This can be argued rigorously for a discrete sample space but not sure how to extend that in this continuous experiment. Would be happy to know if you find any fallacy in this argument.

Imagine you have four real numbers in the interval $[0,4]$. What's the probability that the maximum difference is $1$ (both $|a-b|$ and $|a-b + 4|$)? Isn't that exactly the same question (but easier to comprehend and calculate)? :-)

Thanks for your comments! Very helpful!

Your mistake is easier to explain in a discrete version of the problem.
There are four people, and each person is born in a random month of the year, independently of each other. Assume that all twelve months are equally likely. Imagining these months arranged in a circle, we ask, what is the probability that all four people's birth-months lie in some quarter-circle? That is, what is the probability there exist three consecutive months which contain all four people's birth-months (where December and January are consecutive)?
Here is the method you are suggesting, translated to the discrete setting. Let $X$ denote "the" three-month interval containing all birth-months. Given $X$ is equal to some particular interval (like March-April-May), the probability all months lie in $X$ is $(3/12)^4=1/256$. Since $X$ is equally likely to be any of the $12$ intervals, we get $P(A)=\sum P(A\mid X=x)P(X=x)=\sum \frac1{256}\cdot \frac1{12}=\frac1{256}$.
Notice how I put "the" in scare quotes in the last paragraph. This is the problem; there may be multiple valid choices for $X$. For example, if everyone is born in October, then $X$ could be Aug-Sept-Oct, or Sept-Oct-Nov, or Oct-Nov-Dec. This means that the case where all four people are born in October is triple-counted by the method in the last paragraph. Similarly, outcomes where all people are born in two consecutive months will be double-counted, because there are two possibilities for $X$.
Furthermore, $X$ is not even a random variable. It is a mistake to multiply by $P(X=x)$ in the previous paragraph. This is like saying that there is a fifth random quantity, $X$, and that in addition to the four points lying in some arc, you also need $X$ to have the correct value in order to succeed. This shows that your calculation does not model the problem you are trying to solve.

Here is the correct solution.
There are four points, numbered $1$ to $4$. Supposing all four of those points do land in some arc of angle $\pi/2$, then we will call the clockwise-most point in that arc the leader. For each $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$, let $E_i$ be the event that the $i^\text{th}$ point is the leader. You can then show the following:

$P(E_i)=(\frac{\pi/2}{2\pi})^3=1/64$ for each $i$.

The events $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4$ are disjoint (in the sense that $P(E_i\cap E_j)=0$, $i\neq j$).

$A=E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3\cup E_4$.


Combining these three points, you get $P(A)=4\cdot P(E_1)=\frac1{16}$.

Thanks! Perfectly clear

The mistake in the logic has been explained well in the previous answers, but here's a quick argument for that involves $n=2,3$ points that may help elucidate the problem. The first point can be chosen to be at $\theta_1=0$ due to the periodicity of the problem, and the second point can be anywhere within the arc $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ so the probability of choosing it is $1/2$, but by using your logic the probability should have been $1/16$ instead, which is incorrect. If one more point is added, and the first one landed at $\theta_2=x$, then the third point can be chosen in the arc $(-\pi/2+x,\pi/2)$ when $x>0$ or the arc $(-\pi/2,\pi/2+x), x<0$. The length of this arc is $\pi-|x|$. Thus, the probability that all points are included in an arc of length $\pi/2$ is given by
$$P(\mu(I)\leq \pi/2)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}P(\mu(I)\leq \pi/2|\theta_2=x)f_{\theta_2}(x)dx=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\pi-|x|}{2\pi}\frac{dx}{2\pi}=\frac{3}{16}$$
Simply put, in your argument for 4 points, the conditional probability $P(\mu(I)\leq \pi/2|\theta_3=y,\theta_2=x)$ has not been calculated properly and it definitely depends on the positions $x,y$ where the previous points landed.
Finally, let's generalize this problem. To make this problem tractable and achieve a calculation with arbitary number of points $n$, we need to break down the problem into disjoint events. We consider $n$ points on a circle and we ask for the probability for all of them to belong in an arc of length $2\pi p, p\leq 1/2$.
To find disjoint events that describe the problem we consider a particular ordering of the points. We pick the clockwise-most as the point with the property such that the distance from one of its nearest neighbors is greater than $2\pi(1-p)$. There is a unique such choice for configurations contained in an arc smaller than $2\pi p$ as long as $p<1/2$.
Then, when ordered, the rest of the points are required to be distributed such that the constraints $0=X_1<X_2<...<X_n<2\pi p $ are satisfied. We can write out the probability for such a configuration since the points are drawn independently:
$$P(0=X_1\leq X_2\leq...\leq X_n\leq 2\pi p)=\int_{0}^{2\pi p}\frac{dx_2}{2\pi}\int_{x_2}^{2\pi p}\frac{dx_3}{2\pi}..\int_{x_{n-1}}^{2\pi p}\frac{dx_n}{2\pi}$$
One can show inductively that $P(0=X_1\leq X_2\leq...\leq X_n\leq 2\pi p)=\frac{p^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$. The above result is the same no matter which ordering of the points we picked, and there are $n!$ possible orderings. The requisite probability thus is given by
$$P(\mu(I)<2\pi p)=n!P(0=X_1\leq X_2\leq...\leq X_n\leq 2\pi p)=n p^{n-1}$$
This trick only works for arcs smaller than half-circles, since for arcs bigger than that there are additional complications.
